# I need to show my table data with group by

Tags: group-by

i have data like this in table

```
ROLL_NO SHOE_NO SHOCKS  CAP SHIRT   TROUSER JACKET
                        
21  7   12  32  28  22  32
22  7   15  30  22  12  22
23  8   16  31  21  14  20
24  9   17  33  28  19  26
25  7   16  30  22  12  22
26  7   15  31  22  12  22
27  8   15  30  22  12  22
28  7   17  30  22  12  22
29  8   15  30      12  22
31  8   15  30  22  12
```

now i need some grouping tricks to show data like this

```
ITEM    SIZE    COUNT
SHOE    7   5
SHOE    8   4
SHOE    9   1
SHOCKS  12  1
SHOCKS  15  5
SHOCKS  16  2
SHOCKS  17  2
CAP 32  1
CAP 30  6
CAP 31  2
CAP 33  1
SHIRT   28  2
SHIRT   22  6
SHIRT   21  1
SHIRT   NULL    1
TROUSER 22  1
TROUSER 12  7
TROUSER 14  1
TROUSER 19  1
JACKET  32  1
JACKET  22  6
JACKET  20  1
JACKET  26  1
JACKET  NULL    1
```

create table script and insert satement is as follow-

```
create table uniform_size (
    ROLL_NO NUMBER UNIQUE,
    SHOE_NO NUMBER,
    SHOCKS NUMBER,
    CAP NUMBER,
    SHIRT NUMBER,
    TROUSER number,
    JACKET NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 21,7,12,32,28,22,32);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 22,7,15,30,22,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 23,8,16,31,21,14,20);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 24,9,17,33,28,19,26);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 25,7,16,30,22,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 26,7,15,31,22,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 27,8,15,30,22,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 28,7,17,30,22,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 29,8,15,30,NULL,12,22);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 31,8,15,30,22,12,NULL);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 32,NULL,15,30,22,12,23);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 33,NULL,15,31,22,12,23);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 34,9,NULL,30,22,12,23);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 35,9,18,31,22,12,23);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 36,9,NULL,30,28,12,23);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 37,9,18,30,22,12,24);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 38,10,19,30,22,12,24);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 39,10,19,30,22,14,24);
INSERT INTO UNIFORM_SIZE VALUES ( 40,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

thank you and regards

i have tried some grouping tricks but didn't got the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to get unique values from each column and get the count of each value.  Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but it seems helpful to me.

```
select 'SHOE' article, SHOE_NO size, count(SHOE_NO) cnt from uniform_size group by SHOE_NO
union all
select 'SHOCKS' article, SHOCKS size, count(SHOCKS) cnt from uniform_size group by SHOCKS
union all 
select 'CAP' article, CAP size, count(CAP) cnt from uniform_size group by CAP
union all 
select 'SHIRT' article, SHIRT size, count(SHIRT) cnt from uniform_size group by SHIRT
union all 
select 'TROUSER' article, TROUSER size, count(TROUSER) cnt from uniform_size group by TROUSER
union all
select 'JACKET' article, JACKET size, count(JACKET) cnt from uniform_size group by JACKET;
```

result

```
SHOE||0
SHOE|7|5
SHOE|8|4
SHOE|9|5
SHOE|10|2
SHOCKS||0
SHOCKS|12|1
SHOCKS|15|7
SHOCKS|16|2
SHOCKS|17|2
SHOCKS|18|2
SHOCKS|19|2
CAP||0
CAP|30|12
CAP|31|4
CAP|32|1
CAP|33|1
SHIRT||0
SHIRT|21|1
SHIRT|22|13
SHIRT|28|3
TROUSER||0
TROUSER|12|14
TROUSER|14|2
TROUSER|19|1
TROUSER|22|1
JACKET||0
JACKET|20|1
JACKET|22|6
JACKET|23|5
JACKET|24|3
JACKET|26|1
JACKET|32|1
```